# django haystack order results by most common term, not by alphabetical

Tags: django, indexing, sql-order-by, django-haystack

I want to order results by the most common hit in a charfield, and not by alphabetical order. So if my query returns results where the charfield has entries C, B, B, A I want results to appear in order B, B, A, C, and not A, B, B, C.

search_indexes.py:

```
c = indexes.CharField(null=True) ###this is the field I want to order by
d1 = indexes.CharField(null=True)
....
dn = indexes.CharField(null=True
```

The following orders by alphabetical, not frequency.

forms.py:

```
sqs = sqs.filter(modelc=c)
sqs = sqs.filter(modeld1=d1)
...
sqs = sqs.filter(modeldn=dn)
sqs = sqs.order_by('modelc')
```

Comment: Did you try sorting by score?

Comment: my understanding is that you need to boost to order by score, and I cannot seem to get field boosting to work. I am running elasticsearch as the backend, and have heard from others that field boosting is not possible with elasticsearch.